Are there any polls in Bangladesh on how the influence of China and India are perceived there?
Bangladesh has been at the intersection of Chinese and Indian efforts to expand their 'soft power' (at least) in that country.
How are all these efforts perceived in Bangladesh? I know there are segments of the population who resent one (and perhaps even the other) of these. Are there any more formal opinion polls in Bangladesh of how the efforts of China and India are perceived?

Can I answer this question using an analysis? I don't know of any such polls, but, as a native citizen, I witnessed the entire thing firsthand.

The best I could find was a poll from 2019 that asked one sort of relevant question, which suggest that average people in Bangladesh viewed India more positively than China, and both more positively than the U.S.:

And, this Pew Poll on China only from July 9, 2024, shows that Bangladesh has a significantly more positive view of China than many other countries in the world, in line with many Southeast Asian, African, and Latin American countries:

A January 2024 story from Al-Jazeera discusses attitudes towards China qualitatively but has no poll data. Basically, the article argues that the January 2024 election results will influence Bangladesh's relationships with China and India, which I could have told you without doing any research whatsoever. Elections matter (whether or not they are free and fair). The Awami League went on to win those elections in an event decried as a "sham."
A July 9, 2024 article likewise discusses the balancing act between China and India for Bangladesh's leaders but says little about how the general public feels about it.

TBH in the first poll the statistical difference between China and the US is within the margin of error, while that of India probably isn't so (relative to either China/US).

@timetakesitstoll You are probably right. On the other hand, a lot has happened in the five years since that poll was taken and it is entirely plausible that opinions have changed. The Pew poll data from this summer is quite a bit more favorable towards China than the 2019 poll, and is asking a very similar question. Pew is 55-16 pro China, the 2019 poll is 47-18 pro China. That's a statistically significant jump. The 2019 poll for India is 52-20 pro-India.
